# Function commenting conventions in R

Tags: r, conventions, comments

I'm fairly new to R, and I have been defining some of my own functions in script files. I'm intending for others to re-use them later, and I can't find any guides on R function commenting conventions. Is there any way for me to make `help("my_function_name")` show some help? If not, do I just document the function in the script file, so that someone has to print out (or open the source of) a script to see the comments?

Thanks,

Hamy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Updating this question December 2019 as the R-universe has changed since 2011 when originally written*

My recommended resource is now http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

*Original answer (links are mostly out of date)*

The canonical way to document your functions and make them accessible to others is to make a package. In order for your package to pass the build checks, you have to supply sufficiently detailed help files for each of your functions / datasets.

Check out http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-R-packages

This blog post from Rob J Hyndman was very useful and one of the easiest for me to follow: http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/building-r-packages-for-windows/

I've started using roxygen to assist in making & compiling packages as of late: http://roxygen.org/

Lots of good resources and people to help when you have questions!

Comment: The link to the blog  post of Rob J Hyndman is broken. 
Alternatively, the pdf can now be found [here](https://robjhyndman.com/research/Rpackages.pdf).

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd urls are 404

Comment: @Borealis - I added a new reference that's accurate as of 2019...impressive this question still gets traction nearly a decade later.

Answer (score 19):

Another (and lower key) alternative you could look into are the `comment()` and `attr()` functions to add some meta data to your functions. Here's a quick and silly example:

```
FOO <- function(x,y) {
 x + y 
}

attr(FOO, "comment") <- "FOO performs simple addition"

#This can be arbitrary. "comment" is special. see ?comment for details.
attr(FOO, "help") <- "FOO expects two numbers, and it will add them together"
```

You can then see everything associated with `FOO` by using `attributes()`:

```
> attributes(FOO)
$source
[1] "function(x,y) {" " x + y "         "}"              

$comment
[1] "FOO performs simple addition"

$help
[1] "FOO expects two numbers, and it will add them together"
```

Or extract specific parts:

```
> attr(FOO, "help")
[1] "FOO expects two numbers, and it will add them together"
attr(FOO, "comment")
[1] "FOO performs simple addition"
```

And in the case of comment, use `comment()`:

```
> comment(FOO)
[1] "FOO performs simple addition"
```

In the long term, writing your own package will almost certainly be worth the overhead and time investment, but if for some reason that isn't practical in the short term - here's another option.

Comment: +1 I do this all the time, especially for saved workspaces and functions that aren't overly complicated but you want to know "what they do" quickly.

Answer (score 7):

You will have to put functions into a package (which makes porting function REALLY easy). I have written a [short post](http://danganothererror.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/building-an-r-package-under-windows-without-c-c-or-fortran-code/) about it a while ago with links (I hope they still work) to some relevant documents that expand the subject.

You can generate help files "on the fly" using [roxygen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen/index.html), [inlinedocs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inlinedocs/index.html).

Comment: Is that a roxygen echo? echo?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not building a package, you can use [`docstring`](https://github.com/Dasonk/docstring) package, which offers similar functions as Python's docstring.

```
library(docstring)

square <- function(x){

    #' Square a number
    #'
    #' Calculates the square of the input
    #'
    #' @param x the input to be squared

    return(x^2)
}
```

You can see the comments by calling `?square`.
[image]
[output](https://github.com/Dasonk/docstring/raw/master/docs/images/square_rstudio.png)

[This tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docstring/vignettes/docstring_intro.html) might be helpful.